# Extracting user details from a DB and using these to login via Jmeter

Tags: loops, jdbc, jmeter

I have a db full of users (3 million) that I want to use during testing, I do not want to create or use the csv file method for this. I would like to pick a new user each time to login with.

In my test plan I have a once only controller where I have put a JDBC connection to my DB and two JDBC processors

1. one that counts the number of users in the DB $users
2. one that selects all the emails in the DB that fit a certain criteria I return this as an an array of emails $emails

What I am struggling with is using these to construct a loop that selects a different email each time so I can pass these as inputs to my login requests. Each thread should use a different email address.

Comment: What's your beef against a CSV file? Scalable tests are desirable in jmeter  - lighter tests allow you to run more threads for the same amount of resources, and afford you more stable tests. Unless there is a very good reason to create JDBC calls during the test, I would highly recommend using a CSV approach.

Comment: What does your query look like? How are you storing an array in a variable, are you using `vars.putObject()` ?

Comment: No beef against the CSV approach, what I am keen to avoid is using the same bunch of users every time I run the test so that my db caching doesn't skew my results.Thus I'd like to maintain an index and iterate over all of the users in the  DB. A CSV with 3 million lines isn't really feasible.

Comment: Well, you're not fetching all 3 million rows in your JDBC query either. Run the query once offline, and use the results in your CSV file! Of course this might not be a good way to go, if your query parameters are only determined at runtime. CSV isn't an all compassing answer, but if feasible, just a more resource efficient way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `variable names` textbox in your JDBC sampler?

You can use the `_index` notation to access the results returned by the JDBC sampler. For example, if your query returns a single column of data, and you put `emails` in the `variable names` textbox, then:

`emails_#` will contain the number of result rows
`emails_1` will contain the first row value
`emails_2` will contain second row value and so on..

ref: [JDBC Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following SQL query to get random email:

```
SELECT email FROM table WHERE your_criteria = 'something' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

directly in the [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) where random email is required.

Pre/Post Processors and Timers processing time is not included into response time by default so it is quite "safe" operation (unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)).

Comment: How do you account for this: *Each thread should use a different email address*

Comment: I guess via `ORDER BY RAND()` bit